# How to save my datas in jTable

Tags: jframe, netbeans-8

I did my frame by using jFrame.There is a jTable on it with 6 columns and 15 rows.I want to save my table on file or text.And I want to get them in same columns and same rows when i click on load.How can i do that ?

thanks in advance.

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},},
        new String [] {
            "İSİM", "NO", "İZİN NEDENİ", "İZİNE ÇIKIŞ TARİHİ", "İZİN GÜNÜ", "İZİN BİTİŞ TARİHİ", "KALAN izin hakkı"
        }
    ));
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please provide some more context to your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @nhee i want to save my datas.when i exit program all my datas in table getting lost.[link](http://i57.tinypic.com/zk00pe.jpg) i want to keep whats in my table on this image and i have no idea what should i do

Comment: noone knows how can i save it to excel ? or somewhere all i want to do is when i close program my datas on jtable should stay.

Comment: Have you tried googling? First result: [How To Export Records From JTable To MS Excel](https://sites.google.com/site/teachmemrxymon/java/export-records-from-jtable-to-ms-excel)